# SettingKey type for loose coupled Project and ModuleID

Tags: sbt

I'm writing a sbt plugin for assembling loosely coupled modules/services for runtime and testing. These modules could be a project (in this multi-project build) or a ModuleID (resolved through Ivy). The project structure may look like this:

root

- foo
- bar
- foobar

There is no classpath dependency between the projects. Lets say project foo is self contained. Project bar would need foo to be started to test bar. And project foobar will need both foo, bar, and a module referenced by org.sample.mymodule-1.0.0 to be started.

The projects foo, bar, and foobar are declared within root (and have other project dependencies not listed here, but no dependencies among them). To implement these, we need to:

1. Declare a setting (looseCoupledDependencies) that can be set inside a subproject (for instance foobar) that can reference other modules as subprojects or artifacts.
2. For each of these, find the classpath and start a JVM with the that classpath and start the module at run/test time.

I'm still stuck with #1. 1) I cannot find a type that could represent both Project and ModuleID and 2) I cannot reference projects in root from within foobar (given I have a SettingKey[Seq[Project]] in settings - this is also not yet the right type).

How could I achieve such a setting that could easily take care of both types and allow references from subprojects? Thanks.

Comment: I can't fully answer right now, but given a ProjectRef/ProjectREference you should be able to get the ModuleID vis the key:  `projectId in <project reference>`.

Comment: Not quite working yet. Adding something like:

Comment: Thanks a lot, but not quite working yet. Adding something like:
`startProjects += bar in root`
into foobar/build.sbt gives such errors:
`error: not found: value bar`
 - Putting `bar in root` into parentheses does not help.
In the plugin, startProjects has been declared as `SettingKey[Seq[Project]]` and added to settings. So using it in root like
`startProjects += bar`
works perfectly fine. Just not when we want to cross-reference between child projects.

Comment: Some breakthrough. Defining the startProjects in root/build.sbt such as `startProjects in foobar += bar` does work. But that restricts us to declaring this just in root/build.sbt. Can't specify this in foobar/build.sbt. Not perfect, but would get me moving forward for now.